# Exercising with pthreads but I am having some unexpected behaviours in my code

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I want to make a program in c which is going to sum the square numbers of an array using pthreads to achieve a parallel execution of the code, but when executing the code in a linux enviroment I get the ***segmentation fault(core dumbed)*** message.

Weird thing is that when I am running the same exact code on a windows environment via DevC++, the code is executed with no problems.

Other than that, it seems that only 1 thread is doing the job done resulting on a serial execution.

I don't know if I am wrong but `pthread_self()` is returning the same ID. I am still a newbie to pthreads and programming in general and I can't locate the problem, so I need your help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void *calculation(int table[], int k);


pthread_mutex_t sum_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int  n, p, sum = 0;

int main()
{
    int i, k=0, check, *table;

    printf("Give the number of threads:\n");
    scanf("%d",&p);
    pthread_t threads[p];

    printf("Give the number of elements of the table:");
    do{
    printf("The number of elements must be an integral multiple of the number of threads\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    check=n%p;
    if(check!=0){
    printf("Jesus how hard is it?\n");
    printf("Try one more time\n");
    printf("Give the number of elements of the table:\n");
    }
    }while(check!=0);

    table = (int*) malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    if(table == NULL){          
        printf("Error! Memory not allocated.\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    printf("Give the elements of the table:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d",&table[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<p;i++){                                                       //thread creation
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, calculation(table, k), NULL);
        k++;                                                                //k is a variable used to seperate table, explained later
    }
    for(i=0;i<p;i++){
        pthread_join(threads[i],NULL);
    }

    printf("Sum of vector= %d\n",sum);

    free(table);
    exit(0);
    return 0;
}

void *calculation(int table[], int k){
    int i;
    int local_sum=0;
    for(i=(n/p)*k;i<(n/p)*(k+1);i++)                                        //this algorithm seperates the table into equivelant pieces and
    {                                                                       //every pthread is calculating its given piece then stores that value in its local variable sum
        if((n/p)>n){                                                        //then it is updating the global variable
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }
        local_sum+=pow(table[i], 2);
        printf("Thread's %lu calculation is %d\n", pthread_self(), local_sum);
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&sum_mutex);                                         //mutex used here to protect the critical code
    sum += local_sum;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&sum_mutex);
}
```

If I am not mistaken a thread is running a different "copy" of the code, thus local variable is different for each thread. After calculating the local_sum it updates the global sum which is being protected for obvious reasons.

As I said, in a windows environment this code is running smoothly but it seems that the same pthread is doing all the work. Instead the work should be seperated in as many pieces as threads exist.

Don't forget the fact that in a linux environment the core is not runnning at all resulting in the error: segmentation fault(core dumbed).

Comment: regarding: `pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, calculation(table, k), NULL);`  the function name cannot have parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the man page, declaration of pthread_create

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                     void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

3rd argument of pthread_create is a function pointer, which takes `void*` as argument.
In you case you have two arguments `void *calculation(int table[], int k);`

Also the way you passing argument to `pthread_create` is wrong, it should only be function name not with its parameter.(Read more about callback functions). The last `NULL` should be the parameters. In your case you want to pass `table` and `k` but it should be a single pointer.

`pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, calculation(table, k), NULL);`

Below, I have modified the code and introduces a new `struct thread_arg` which contains `table` and `k`, this `struct` will be passed to your `calculation` which then unwraps it and use normally.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct thread_arg {
        int *table;
        int k;
};

void *calculation(void *);

pthread_mutex_t sum_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int  n, p, sum = 0;

int main()
{
        int i, k=0, check, *table;

        printf("Give the number of threads:\n");
        scanf("%d",&p);
        pthread_t threads[p];

        printf("Give the number of elements of the table:");
        do{
                printf("The number of elements must be an integral multiple of the number of threads\n");
                scanf("%d",&n);
                check=n%p;
                if(check!=0){
                        printf("Jesus how hard is it?\n");
                        printf("Try one more time\n");
                        printf("Give the number of elements of the table:\n");
                }
        }while(check!=0);

        table = (int*) malloc(n * sizeof(int));
        if(table == NULL){
                printf("Error! Memory not allocated.\n");
                exit(0);
        }

        printf("Give the elements of the table:\n");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
                scanf("%d",&table[i]);
        }

        // edit: since I know the size allocated memory for th_args;
        struct thread_arg th_args[p];

        for(i=0;i<p;i++){                                                       //thread creation
                th_args[i].table = table;
                th_args[i].k = k;
                pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, calculation, &th_args[i]);
                k++;                                                                //k is a variable used to seperate table, explained later
        }
        for(i=0;i<p;i++){
                pthread_join(threads[i],NULL);
        }

        printf("Sum of vector= %d\n",sum);

        free(table);
        exit(0);
        return 0;
}

void *calculation(void *data){
        int i;
        int local_sum=0;
        int *table;
        int k;

        struct thread_arg *th_args = data;
        k = th_args->k;
        table = th_args->table;

        printf("shubham: thread_spawned\n");
        for(i=(n/p)*k;i<(n/p)*(k+1);i++)                                        //this algorithm seperates the table into equivelant pieces and
        {                                                                       //every pthread is calculating its given piece then stores that value in its local variable sum
                if((n/p)>n){                                                        //then it is updating the global variable
                        pthread_exit(NULL);
                }
                local_sum+=pow(table[i], 2);
                printf("Thread's %lu calculation is %d\n", pthread_self(), local_sum);
        }

        pthread_mutex_lock(&sum_mutex);                                         //mutex used here to protect the critical code
        sum += local_sum;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&sum_mutex);

        // edit: function returs NULL;
        return NULL;
}
```

Edit1: Now `calculation` returns `NULL`, handled the `k++` case by creating `p` th_args

Comment: I totally misunderstood the declaration, I thought the 4th parameter was an argument of the thread itself, how silly am I. This solves the second problem of my code, which was that only 1 thread was working. But one problem still exists. I still get the __segmentaion fault (core dumped)__. Do you have any idea on how can I fix this?

Comment: @ΠαναγιώτηςΓκιώκας can you check it now. I made few edits.

Comment: @rafix07 thanks, I actually forgot to malloc the memory for th_args and did not noticed that k is incrementing.

Comment: @rafix07 @Shubham Thank you both this is the solution on my problem. I am having a hard time figuring out this block of code ```       for(i=0;i<p;i++){                                                       //thread creation
                th_args[i].table = table;
                th_args[i].k = k;
                pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, calculation, &th_args[i]);
                k++;                                                                //k is a variable used to seperate table, explained later
        }``` can you explain to me this initializing thing you are doing?

Comment: I have created an array `th_args` of length `p`. In `for` loop, I'm filling structure with the required values, check ` k` is incremented. We are passing address of `struct thread_arg` to `calculation`.